# Bundler Starting with full path - issue

Tags: ruby, centos, bundle, bundler

I am trying to run bundle from inside a folder of my RoR app and it works as expected.

However, when I try to run it using the full path (need this for the cron jobs), it just fails with the error "in `require': no such file to load -- bundler (LoadError)" . Any ideas how to fix this?

Comment: please make sure that 'gem install bundler' is done.

Comment: It is - I already checked with "bundle show" and I get the gems installed. The issue is - I can use it by just typing "bundle" as the command, but when I write out the full path to bundle it gives me that error.

Answer (score 0):

Just found out that my original issue for the cron was the PATH variable, so I just directly set it up in the cron.